# "READ-ONLY ERROR" in react-native mobile application development?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native, mobile-application

```
const generateRandomBetween = (min,max,exclude) =>  {
    min=Math.ceil(min);
    max =Math.floor(max);
    const rndnum= Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min)) + min;
    if(rndnum===exclude)
    {
        generateRandomBetween = (min,max,exclude)
    }
    else
    {
       return rndnum;
    }
```

"here this code is generating random number between 1-100 and exclude used for computer not guessing the number in first try"
"

Comment: Not sure what exactly is causing the error but you need `return generateRandomBetween = (min,max,exclude)`

Answer (score 0):

`generateRandomBetween` in your case is a function that is assigned to a `const` variable.
Variables defined as `const` can not be reassigned, unlike `let` or `var`.

Hence, whenever the value of `rndnum` is equal to the value of `exclude`,
you are trying to assign a new value to `generateRandomBetween`.

Im assuming that what you meant to say is that if `rndnum` is equal to `exclude`, re-run the function.
If that is the case, you should remove the "equals" sign.

**Example:**

```
const generateRandomBetween = (min,max,exclude) =>  {
    min=Math.ceil(min);
    max =Math.floor(max);
    const rndnum= Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min)) + min;
    if(rndnum===exclude)
    {
        generateRandomBetween(min,max,exclude)
    }
    else
    {
       return rndnum;
    }
}
```

---

**Note:** we can also make this code a bit cleaner if we do a small syntax refactor.

```
const generateRandomBetween = (min,max,exclude) => {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    const rndnum = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min)) + min;
    if(rndnum === exclude) {
        return generateRandomBetween(min,max,exclude);
    }
    return rndnum;
}
```

The functionality remains the same, we just make the `else` block implicit, so to speak.